# Why does ODS Excel Autofilter disable the filters in the resulting workbook?

Tags: excel, sas, autofilter

I am using ODS Excel instead of ODS Tagsets.Excelxp for my current projects. It went all good so far and I like it better than the tagsets.excelxp though it has some differences.

I am creating .xlsx file named 'CRE Reporting for 03312017.xlsx'. It has three sheets-named sheet one, sheet two and sheet three. I have used the option:

```
Autofilters='ALL'
```

for all three sheets.

When I first open the produced file, the Filter option under the 'Data' in Excel becomes inactive and I cannot do filtering. It is active in second and third sheets. But, if i come back to the first sheet from sheet two or sheet three then the Filter becomes active for sheet one as well and I can do filtering. If I close the file without saving the changes for sheet one, I again need to go to sheet two or sheet three to make it active for sheet one.

Is that an issue with the ODS Excel that needs to be fixed or is there a fix for that which I am not aware of? There is no such issue with ODS Tagset.excelxp.

Comment: What version of SAS is running? Try doing `PROC SETINIT;`, it will report the version after "Current version:"

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you only output the first worksheet (as an experiment)?

Comment: I have 9.04.01M3P062415 in my machine now.

Comment: That's M3, so that would support my answer I think. Do the worksheets appear grouped?

Comment: The worksheets appear grouped first but it appears ungrouped when I go to the next sheet and come back again.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible or not, just a thought. Is it possible to create a dummy sheet and hide the whole sheet using ODS Excel? This will let me ungroup the other sheet and use the filter option.

Comment: Hiding a worksheet might not be possible unless you do DDE (ugly solution, might not be possible in corporate environments). Maybe the best you can do is create a cover sheet

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with SAS automatically grouping worksheets when autofilter is used. Grouped worksheets will disable the filter function. When you switch between the worksheets, it will ungroup them, and you get the filtering functionality again.

This is a problem with SAS 9.4 TS1M3 that is fixed in 9.4 TS1M4 as described here:

[56878: The ODS destination for Excel generates grouped worksheets when multiple sheets are produced](https://support.sas.com/kb/56/878.html)

> The AUTOFILTER= ODS EXCEL statement option does not display values to filter when multiple worksheets are generated with the ODS destination for Excel. This occurs because the ODS destination for Excel generates grouped Excel worksheets by default when multiple sheets are produced.

To verify:

*Ungrouped*

[image: Ungrouped]

*Grouped*

[image]